# Perforce Integrate files from another server

Tags: perforce

I was reading this [How to create private remote perforce branches and push to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330832/how-to-create-private-remote-perforce-branches-and-push-to-it) so I thought this would be a good place to post and talk about my issue. I have a p4 server hosted on a physical machine in my office. However, I'm trying to migrate it to the cloud running Ubuntu 20.04. It's currently running on Windows Server. I've read this guide: https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3080 however, the problem here is that this completely overrides the current data on p4. What I want to do is simply merge the data or append it from my other server to my new master server. Does anyone know if this is possible? The goal is to migrate from windows to linux, without overriding the default depots on a linux setup.

Comment: To clarify -- does your server in the cloud have data on it already?

Comment: And if so, is it the same set of files, or an entirely different set (with different depot paths etc)?  Merging two different variant histories of the same file tree is very different from combining two disjoint sets!

Comment: So the server that I setup is a blank slate fresh install of helix-p4d, but the files that are on my windows server are from months worth of use. I want to append the files and metadata from my windows server to my fresh install on amazon

Comment: You should follow the migration guide, then.  The "default depots" aren't something you need to worry about preserving; just migrating what you have on Windows to your Linux setup is a lot more straightforward than a scenario which involves existing files in both locations.